# Wordpress WP_Query not using keyword from url query value?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a form to change the values in a `WP_Query` on a custom post type. I have 2 select fields using taxonomy values, and a keyword search. The select fields are working fine, however the keyword doesn't affect the query (although it shows up in the url query string).

The code for the keyword field is:

`<input type="text" placeholder="Välj" name="referenser_keyword">`

and the code for taking the query values is:

```
global $wp_query;

if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['referenser_material'])) {

    $materialVal = $wp_query->query_vars['referenser_material'];

} else {

    $materialVal = '';

}

if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['referenser_segment'])) {

    $segmentVal = $wp_query->query_vars['referenser_segment'];

} else {

    $segmentVal = '';

}

if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['referenser_keyword'])) {

    $keywordVal = $wp_query->query_vars['referenser_keyword'];

} else {

    $keywordVal = '';

}

$filteredLoop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'             => 'referenser',
            'posts_per_page'        => 4,
            'referenser_material'   => $materialVal,
            'referenser_segment'    => $segmentVal,
            's'                     => $keywordVal,
            'exact'                 => false,
            'sentence'              => true
        )
    );
```

If I change the `$keywordVal` value in the `} else {` from `''` to a string, it works using the value I've entered, which makes me think it's always **not** set (and going through as empty in the query).

Comment: your not showing how you set the query var. im assuming you are not setting them correctly, use `$_GET['referenser_material']` to parse public url parameters

Comment: You're right, I hadn't defined all 3 correctly, I changed what I had in functions.php and it's working fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't defined the query variables correctly, adding the following to `functions.php` fixed it.

```
function referenser_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "referenser_material";
  $vars[] = "referenser_segment";
  $vars[] = "referenser_keyword";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'referenser_query_vars_filter' );
```